# For loop in range incrementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Why does "c" in the for loop is not incrementing?

```
def solution(s):
    for c in range(len(s)):
        if s[c] == s[c].upper():
            s = s[:c] + ' ' + s[c:]
            c += 1
    return s
print(solution('helloWorld'))
```

The output should be `"hello World"`, however, when i add a space `" "` i also increment the `c`, but it doesn't works.
Current output is `'hello     World'`

Comment: Did you mean `print(solution("helloWorld"))`?

Comment: yea, my mistake, but it still doesn't works right

Comment: Please [edit] the question to reflect that. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of:

```py
for c in range(len(s)):
```

as the `c` being "set" by the range every loop iteration. The range keeps track of what iteration number it's at.

I think you mean something like this:

```
def solution(s):
    c = 0
    while c < len(s):
        if s[c] == s[c].upper():
            s = s[:c] + ' ' + s[c:]
            c += 1
        c += 1
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `c` is automatically re-set on the next iteration, `for c in ...`. In general, you'll have this problem when you try modifying something while you're iterating over it, because the indices won't match up. [Here's another example](/q/6260089/4518341).

You could use a `while` loop instead, but actually, it's easier to build a new output string:

```
def solution(s):
    out = ''
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():  # I also simplified this
            out += ' '
        out += c
    return out

print(solution("helloWorld"))  # -> hello World
```

Although, it's best practice to use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build strings, like this with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
def solution(s):
    return ''.join(' '+c if c.isupper() else c for c in s)

print(solution("helloWorld"))  # -> hello World
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, because you didn't call the function.

Comment: That seems to be a typo since OP wrote "Current output is `'hello     World'`", which is in fact what you get if you run the function